# Configuração Rede via prompt

Tags: cmd, proxy, prompt

Como desativo via prompt de comando as caixas de seleção "Usar script de configuração automática" e também "Não usar servidor proxy para endereços locais"?

Para desabilitar o proxy, estou usando o comando:

```
 "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

Gostaria de saber como posso desativar as outras duas caixas de seleção seguindo a mesma ideia do comando que ja tenho. Assim deixo tudo em um .bat

[image: Minha tela de configuração do proxy]

Answer (score 1):

Crie um arquivo com a extensão .reg(exemplo: proxy.reg) com o código abaixo:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"MigrateProxy"=dword:00000001
"ProxyEnable"=dword:00000001
"ProxyHttp1.1"=dword:00000000
"AutoDetect"=dword:00000000
"ProxyServer"="http://seu_servidor_proxy:80"
"ProxyOverride"=""
```

Aqui você ativa ou desativa o proxy

Ativo

```
"ProxyEnable"=dword:00000001
```

inativo

```
"ProxyEnable"=dword:00000000
```

Para ativar novamente o "Usar script de configuração automática", modifique a linha

```
"AutoDetect"=dword:00000000
```

para

```
"AutoDetect"=dword:00000001
```

Para ativar novamente o "Não usar servidor proxy para endereços locais", modifique a linha

```
"ProxyOverride"=""
```

para

```
"ProxyOverride"="<local>"
```

E para colocar o seu .reg em um .bat é simples:

```
REGEDIT.EXE  /S  "proxy.reg"
```

Comment: Fiz o que você comentou, mas quando executo o .reg, ele me exibe esta mensagem: Não é possível importarl C:\......... O arquivo especificado não é um script do Registro. Você pode importar somente arquivos do registro

Comment: Tente desta forma: REGEDIT.EXE  /S  "%~dp0\proxy.reg" ou colocando o caminho completo onde esta o seu arquivo .reg

Comment: Acredito que precise disso `Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00` no começo do arquivo para ser reconhecido

Answer (score 0):

Faz da seguinte maneira que vai dar certo:

```
dim oShell
set oShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
configURL = "script_de_proxy"
configURL0 = ""

if msgbox("Navegar com Proxy?", vbQuestion or vbYesNo) = vbYes then
oShell.RegWrite "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\AutoConfigURL", configURL, "REG_SZ"
else
oShell.RegWrite "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\AutoConfigURL", configURL0, "REG_SZ"
end if

Set oShell = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Faz da Seguinte maneira:

```
dim oShell
set oShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
configURL = "AQUI SEU SCRIPT DE CONFIGURAÇÃO"

if msgbox("Habilitar Proxy?", vbQuestion or vbYesNo) = vbYes then
oShell.RegWrite "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\AutoConfigURL", configURL, "REG_SZ"
else
oShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable", 0, "REG_DWORD"

End if

Set oShell = Nothing
```